# Onload and show checked radio button of a div tag

Tags: jquery

I found a source code from [here](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=jquery-show-hide-div-using-radio-button). The div content will show when the radio button is checked. 

I need to show div content of checked radio button when the page is onload.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "red") {
            $(".box").not(".red").hide();
            $(".red").show();
        }
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "green") {
            $(".box").not(".green").hide();
            $(".green").show();
        }
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "blue") {
            $(".box").not(".blue").hide();
            $(".blue").show();
        }
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kdjetgtz/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After assigning the event handler find the checked ones and trigger the `change` event (with [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) or [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/)) on them.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="radio"]')
        .change(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("value") == "red") {
                $(".box").not(".red").hide();
                $(".red").show();
            }
            if ($(this).attr("value") == "green") {
                $(".box").not(".green").hide();
                $(".green").show();
            }
            if ($(this).attr("value") == "blue") {
                $(".box").not(".blue").hide();
                $(".blue").show();
            }
        })
        .filter(function(checkbox) {
            return $(this).prop("checked");
        })
        .trigger("change");    // or .change();
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/opvxwx0s/2/)

Comment: If there is no radio button is checked, the blue box will be displayed too. It should be clean and no div content will be displayed. Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/opvxwx0s/1/

Comment: Thanks Andreas. This is what I need exactly.